# What are the key differences between "SSH tunnels" and "Squid reverse IPs" in regards to web page scraping and private browsing?

Tags: proxy, ssh-tunneling, http-proxy, squid, privacy

What are the key differences between *"SSH tunnels"* and *"Squid reverse IPs"* in regards to web page scraping and private browsing?

Interested to know if there are any differences between using *"SSH tunnels"* and *"Squid reverse IPs"* and how they connect to a website.

**For example:** do they leave the same HTTP headers and JavaScript system info in a targets' website logs and in JavaScript based analytics software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private browsing is a complicated thing.

A SSH tunnel can protect you from some kind of sniffing and "man-in-the-middle" attack inside your network, or other LAN focused attack. It will basically connect you to a host, and encrypt the connection between you and this hosts using ssh and add this one to the "path" before you access the site. If the site is http, the information will still be unencripted between your ssh tunnel "jumpbox" and the site. No alteration to the http headers, but javascript could act different, for example: You are using a Windows workstation, and connect to a OpenBSD virtual box somewhere on the internet before access a site. A javascript that would probe your Contry and your Operating System will have the information available to the SSH tunel box ip address.

The same way, when using a ssh tunnel on a VPS that you have paid, will not bring "that privacy", since this VPS have a valid ip on the internet, and records of what you have accessed may be available to the site owner. If you make something "wrong" on the internet, you are still a valid person that made a contract with the VPS provider, and they can getter.

---

Having a reverse proxy somewhere, could help you on privacy, but will have the same "legal" caveats of the ssh hosted tunnel, and information accessed through the reverse proxy will not be encripted when needed(aka: http) between you and the proxy

Comment: Sounds like you're saying Squid proxies are generally better/ more secure.

Comment: No. You´ll have more security when connecting to a ssh or vpn tunnel. :)